# Style of jQuery source for event shortcut methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the jQuery source:

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
});
```

Is there a reason to start with a string of event types and then split that string into an array, rather than use an array to begin with: `['blur', 'focus', 'focusin', 'focusout', 'load',...]`? And if you're going to start with a string, why not use a single string rather than concatenate three strings?

Comment: 1 word, readability.

Comment: Just a matter of taste I think

Comment: The three strings are clearly catagorized into different events, and are likely assembled from a raw source code. The first category mostly deal with viewport and click events, the second deals with mouse events and the last deals with context menu and input events.

Comment: The concatenation is due to the fact that strings can't wrap lines in Javascript. This is clearly not minified, so expanding across three lines is to help us read and understand it.